# I want to add an option in the header where customer can select his city from the given options

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce, bootstrap-modal

I am designing an eCommerce website using woocommerce and Flatsome Theme in WordPress. I'm planning to deliver fruits and vegetables only in two cities. 
Now I want a popup when someone arrives at my website which asks Select where you want to deliver and it gives the option for two cities only. When users select one option that selection must be placed in the header.
I tried a bootstrap modal for it. and it is working fine. Now when the user selects a product and moves to the product page that pop up appears again which is not comfortable. I just want it to appear on the home page and the selection a user made there must remain on any other page he/she moves.
If someone has a better idea to perform such function, please share or if you have a solution in this program then it will be appreciated.

HTML code is

```
<img style="height:20px;" src="logo.png" >
<a type="button" id="hash" class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter">
    Select Your Location
</a>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalCenter" data-backdrop="false" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="hasha">Select Your Location</h5>
          <!-- <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
          </button> -->
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body text-center">
            <div class="row">

                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a id="btnsave" ><img style="height:80px;" src="tajMahal.png" ></a>
                    <p id="first">Indirapuram</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <a id="btnsaveone" ><img style="height:80px;" src="mumbai.jpg" ></a>
                    <p id="firstone">Faridabad</p>

                </div>
            </div>


        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <p> ©2020 Grofers Inc.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `session` or `cookies` to save the choise. On bootstrap, following the [Usage](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#options) section

```
$('#exampleModalCenter').modal({show: false})
```

Then, on each page (products, orders etc...) you can check through `session` or `cookies` if a country choice exists, otherwise:

```
$('#exampleModalCenter').modal('show');
```